# Facebook users which have their save surfing account setting to unsecured cannot visit a secured Facebook App

Tags: facebook, http, https

If you have the Save Surfing setting in your account settings in Facebook set to unsecured, you notice you use Facebook via HTTP. Of course if you set it to On, you surf via HTTPS.

Now all Facebook apps are using HTTPS since Facebook doesn't allow apps to use HTTP since October 2011. But if a user (with no HTTPS on their Facebook account) wants to visit the Secured HTTPS App it just gives an empty page.

Is this a bug from Facebook, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now all Facebook apps are using HTTPS since Facebook doesnt allow apps to use HTTP since October 2011.

That’s not true.

All canvas/page tab apps must offer the *option* to be accessed via HTTPS – but should offer HTTP as well.

> But if a user (with no HTTPS on there Facebook account) wants to visit the Secured HTTPS App it just gives an empty page. Is this a bug from Facebook, or?

No, this is an error on your (resp. the app developers) part – in the app settings, there should be URLs set for **both** HTTP and HTTPS.

If that’s the case, then a user browsing Facebook via HTTP has no problem accessing the app as well.

Comment: I did give two urls. But still if you use HTTP as a user the page does not load in.

Comment: Then you might have done something else wrong. What, I can’t tell with so little details. Please update your question with relevant info.

Comment: Okay. For some reason when you are logged in on a sub account you cannot view the content when your main account has save surfing set to OFF.

Comment: if you go to the URL of the page listed for the HTTP (non secure) version of the app, does the page load?  (outside of canvas)